# SQL como criar fk int na TABELA

Tags: mysql, sql

1. Filme
2. COD (int, pk)
3. nome(varchar 20, not null)
4. nascimento(datetime,
   not null)
5. obs(tinybit, not null)
6. obs2(int, fk, not null)

pensei em algo do tipo

```
create table filme (
COD int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
nome varchar(200) NOT NULL,
nascimento datetime NOT NULL,
obs tinyint NOT NULL,
obs2 int NOT NULL

)
```

nao sei criar fk...

como faço para criar um fk int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

você pode fazer assim:

```
create table filme (
COD int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
nome varchar(200) NOT NULL,
nascimento datetime NOT NULL,
obs tinyint NOT NULL,
obs2 int NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY (COD),
FOREIGN KEY (obs2) REFERENCES OutraTabela(ColunaChave)
);
```

se você já criou a tabela pode adicionar uma chave estrangeira FK assim:

```
ALTER TABLE `filme ` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_filme` FOREIGN KEY ( `obs2` ) REFERENCES `OutraTabela` ( `ColunaChave` ) ;
```

Comment: Obrigado! me ajudou muito.... mas estou com outro problema
não consigo adicionar nada na linha quando tem um a fk, por exemplo se tiver fk na obs2 eu nao consigo adicionar nada na tabela, sabe me dizer pq? (to aprendendo sql agora)

Comment: @Jolegendary, como o problema foi resolvido nesta resposta, é ideal você marcá-la como aceita e criar uma nova pergunta. Dá uma lida [nesse link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta)